# A c program file on linux became green and now I cannot edit it

Tags: c, linux

Hi I have a c file in program which is called helloQV.c

I ran the command `gcc -Wall -ansi -std=c99 helloQV.c -o helloQV.c` but now I cannot edit the file helloQV.c, when I open the file in vim it turns out to be just a bunch of random symbols. I realized I should have named the `-o HelloQV.c` to something different. What can I do to undo that change so I can re-edit my helloQV.c file.

Thanks

Comment: What does "became green" mean? If you have not saved a copy of the C file then unfortunately it is gone and you will need to rewrite it. If that is what you want to do and you can't edit it for some reason then delete it first and then create a new C file in your text editor.

Comment: Looks like you've overwritten the source file with the output of the compilation, because of the `-o helloQV.c` on your `gcc` command. Unless you have a backup, then the original is toast. In future, remove the `.c` from the output file name.

Comment: There isn't anything you can do unfortunately. Your compiler wrote over your C code with the compiled output. My best advice is to take this as a learning opportunity for regular backups. Sorry!

Comment: Unfortunately nothing you can do. There might be some backup files generated by your text editor or IDE. What did you use to write your code?

Comment: Dang, I was hoping there was a way to undo it, but thanks guys.

Comment: @alex01011 I am using putty, and using vim as my text editor

Comment: Check the directory for any `.swp` files generated by vim. To avoid similar situations in the future, I would enable `backup` and `writebackup` in vim.

Comment: @dylansun Do you use a version control system, like `git`? If so, you can always get your latest committed version back. If you don't, now seems like a good time to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file showing up green on your terminal using ls means that your file is now an executable file because you’ve overwritten your file with gcc command. There is no way to get your original file back, I'm afraid.